# Как к названию товара подтянуть цену из другой таблицы?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Есть 2 таблицы: *Настройки* и *Учет*.

В *Учет* нужно добавить цену из *Настроек* по названию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить значение "Цена за шт." из первой таблицы во второй, где совпадает название товара. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Варианты:

```
=ВПР(B2;Настройки!$A$2:$B$8;2;)
=ИНДЕКС(Настройки!$B$2:$B$8;ПОИСКПОЗ(B2;Настройки!$A$2:$A$8;))  
=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/(Настройки!$A$2:$A$8=B2);Настройки!$B$2:$B$8)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]